# "Four window layout" or "four windows layout"

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds

To indicate a multiple object layout should I use *four building layout* or *four buildings layout*? Maybe they are both correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to *a 16-foot drop* versus *a drop 16 feet long*, it would be:

> Four-building layout.
>
> Layout consisting of four buildings.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've answered your question in your question by referring to it as a "multiple object layout" rather than a "multiple objects layout".

That being said, drop the `s`. You are describing the layout, not the individual elements.